# Caused by: org.apache.commons.net.MalformedServerReplyException: Could not parse response code

Tags: spring-boot, ftp, spring-integration

I'm developing a spring boot application which reads data from an ftp connection. Have been referring this article. http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html I've added below dependency to pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is my Spring boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FtpApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FtpApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost("localhost");
        sf.setPort(14147);
        sf.setUsername("root");
        sf.setPassword("root");
        return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sf);
    }

    @Bean
    public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(ftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("/");
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel")
    public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
                ftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("ftp-inbound"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                File file = (File) message.getPayload();
                BufferedReader br;
                String sCurrentLine;
                try {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getPath()));
                    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println(message.getPayload());
            }

        };
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {

        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(10));
        return pollerMetadata;
    }
}
```

From the windows explorer I'm adding a file. Now when the control comes to the MessageHandler function, I see the below error. But I can neatly get the file and I see the contents correctly when I read it. But I'm unable to figure out what is the error all about:

```
2016-09-27 08:25:07.548 ERROR 10292 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to obtain pooled item; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create FTPClient
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:274)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:193)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:59)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:209)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:245)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to obtain pooled item; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create FTPClient
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory.getSession(CachingSessionFactory.java:123)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:433)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:232)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create FTPClient
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.getSession(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.getSession(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:41)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:188)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:169)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.net.MalformedServerReplyException: Could not parse response code.
Server Reply: FZS ..... some speacial characters here.....
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:336)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP._connectAction_(FTP.java:418)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._connectAction_(FTPClient.java:966)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._connectAction_(FTPClient.java:954)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:189)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:209)
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.createClient(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.getSession(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:166)
    ... 30 more
```

I'm new to spring integration, please help. Let me know the concepts that I should still consider preparing.

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably connecting to the FileZilla FTP server administrative port (14147).

That port uses a proprietary protocol used by a "FileZilla Server Interface", not FTP, and you are not supposed to connect to it with your application.

Connect to the FTP port instead. By default that is 21. It is configured in "FileZilla Server Interface" on "General Settings" page of the "FileZilla Server Options" as "Listen to these ports".

Comment: Can you please share an article on this. Because I nowhere read this. I think, I went wrong in my prerequisites.

Comment: What article? What do you want to read on this? What you are doing is just a non-sense. And the FileZilla FTP server does not really have any documentation.